# Is Google Maps IOS SDK free to use?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

We have a commercial web application and we are planning to develop android and iOS apps(free) for our customers

1. Is google maps ios sdk is free to use in my app?
2. we want to open google maps app from our app using custom url scheme to show driving   directions. Does this approach have any restrictions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nice FAQ about your questions on Google Developers website:

> Is google maps iOS SDK free to use in my app?

Yes

> we want to open google maps app from our app using custom url scheme to show driving directions. Does this approach have any restrictions?

[Google Map API for Business - Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq?hl=fr#usage_limits)

Answer (score 2):

The google maps iOS sdk is free for use. i have already integrated google map api functionality on one of my phonegap application. After making some minor changes in to the sdk you can enable the real time navigation on the google map as well.

so you can do a lot with the google sdk.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I wonder what about this in usage terms: "You must not use the Service or Content with any products, systems, or applications for or in connection with any of the following:

(i) real time navigation or route guidance, including but not limited to turn-by-turn route guidance that is synchronized to the position of a user's sensor-enabled device." https://developers.google.com/maps/terms. I know some apps are doing "navigation" like function on ios google maps, but wonder if this is completely "legal".

Comment: I am not sure about the answer. But Apple has approved my App with this function.

Comment: Thanks Rajeev for your reply.May be my question is not clear. We are providing our apps as free apps in app store. These apps can be used by our customers by using our web product user credentials. so can we use google maps sdk as free api in this scenario? its good to hear you are able to implement real time navigation using SDK. Can you tell us what changes u did to SDK to achieve this?

Comment: No. Google map for mobile is not FREE. after 50000 request u will have to pay money for each 1000 request

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends, if you are using advanced feature eg Street View, it charges, but for basic feature, it is free for native app, but JS query is not free (eg wrapped by Webview) is not free.

Checkout the official website for more detail and accrete information: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/usage-and-billing